# Why does PHP automatically re-declare sub-functions of functions?

Tags: php

I have the file `Exporter.php`. It's (unfortunately) written like this:

```
function mainFunction() {
    echo 'From main.';
    function secondaryFunction() {
        echo 'From secondary';
    }
    secondaryFunction();
}
```

When I call it once, it's all fine. When I call it twice, it throws:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare secondaryFunction() (previously declared in...`

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: the key is: don't code functions inside functions

Comment: @treyBake Yes. Perhaps people who wrote software that now powers most of the internet should've thought about this but for now, I'm stuck with this.

Comment: why are you stuck with it?

Comment: _“Why is this happening”_ - because that is how functions in PHP work. _“and what can I do about it?”_ - you can a) not call it multiple times, or b) rewrite the code.

Comment: @04FS That might be how they work, but it makes absolutely no sense. First of all, function-scoped functions only make sense as anonymous functions with a name (for structure only). I was thinking there's a way to avoid the error coming up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to accomodate such a construct, just ensure the definition is only parsed once:

```
function mainFunction() {
    echo 'From main.';
    if (!function_exists('secondaryFunction'))
    {
        function secondaryFunction() {
            echo 'From secondary';
        }
    }
    secondaryFunction();
}
```